# Nested Drop won't fire

Tags: javascript, html, draggable

I'm building a Taxonomy Manager in plain javascript (No jQuery), part of this requires that nodes (LI elements) can be dragged and turned into child elements on another LI. I have created a "Child" UL dynamically and a placeholder LI and attached a set of nested event listeners to the UL in order to handle the "drop" part. Sadly the "dragover" works correctly and is firing but the "drop" event is not. What am I missing?

I have pasted my code below but its rather a lot! I have the complete source in codepen [here](http://codepen.io/bUKaneer/pen/IHjwa/) .

```
TaxonomyManager.prototype.attachDragDropEventListeners = function () {
    var manager = this;
    [].forEach.call(this._nodes, function(item) {
      item.draggable = true;
      item.addEventListener('dragstart', dragStartHandler, false);
      item.addEventListener('dragover', dragOverHandler, false);
      item.addEventListener('dragleave', dragLeaveHandler, false);
      item.addEventListener('drop', dropHandler, false);
      item.addEventListener('dragend', dragEndHandler, false);

      manager._dragSource = null;

      function dragStartHandler(e) {
        manager._dragSource = this;
        e.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = 'move';
        e.dataTransfer.setData('text/html', this.innerHTML);
      }

      function dragOverHandler(e) {
        if (e.preventDefault) {
          e.preventDefault(); // Necessary. Allows us to drop.
        }
        removeNewSubTaxonomyPlaceholder();
        if ((this.children.length === 0) && (manager._dragSource !== this)) {
          var ul = document.createElement('UL');
          ul.classList.add('new-sub-taxonomy');
          ul.draggable = true;
          ul.addEventListener('dragstart', dragStartHandler, false);
          ul.addEventListener('dragover', dragOverPlaceholderHandler, false);
          ul.addEventListener('dragleave', dragLeaveHandler, false);
          ul.addEventListener('drop', dropPlaceholderHandler, false);
          ul.addEventListener('dragend', dragEndHandler, false);

          var li = document.createElement("LI");
          li.classList.add('new-sub-taxonomy-placeholder');

          var liText = document.createTextNode("Drop here");
          li.appendChild(liText);
          ul.appendChild(li);
          this.appendChild(ul);          
        }
        e.dataTransfer.dropEffect = 'move'; 
        return false;
      }

      function dragLeaveHandler(e) {
        return false;
      }

      function dropHandler(e) {
        if (e.stopPropagation) {
         e.stopPropagation(); // stops the browser from redirecting.
        }

        if (manager._dragSource !== this) {
          var temp = document.createElement("li");
          manager._dragSource.parentNode.insertBefore(temp, manager._dragSource);
          this.parentNode.insertBefore(manager._dragSource, this);
          temp.parentNode.insertBefore(this, temp);
          temp.parentNode.removeChild(temp);
        }
        return false;      
      }

      function dragEndHandler(e) { 
        removeNewSubTaxonomyPlaceholder();
        return false;
      }

      function dragOverPlaceholderHandler(e) {
        if (e.preventDefault) {
          e.preventDefault(); // Necessary. Allows us to drop.
        }
        console.log('this fires');
        e.dataTransfer.dropEffect = 'move'; 
        return false;
      }

      function dropPlaceholderHandler(e) {
        console.log('this does not fire');
        if (e.stopPropagation) {
         e.stopPropagation(); // stops the browser from redirecting.
        }


        manager.addLeaf(manager._dragSource.firstChild, this.parentNode.parentNode.dataset.id);
        manager.renderTree();


        return false;
      }

      function removeNewSubTaxonomyPlaceholder() {
          var placeholder = document.querySelector('.new-sub-taxonomy');
          if (placeholder) {
            placeholder.parentNode.removeChild(placeholder); 
          }
      }
  });
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically the issue was I needed to add more `e.stopPropagation()` and `e.preventDefault()` statements to the `dragover` and `drop` event handlers on both the parent and child nodes that were hooked up to those events.

I guess that's what you get for coding at 3am!

Answer (score 1):

Take A look at this :[GITHUB link](http://mjsarfatti.com/sandbox/nestedSortable/)

**Jquery JS link :** https://github.com/ilikenwf/nestedSortable/blob/2.0alpha/jquery.mjs.nestedSortable.js

Some Custom Details of used functions

**disableParentChange (2.0)**
Set this to true to lock the parentship of items. They can only be re-ordered within theire current parent container.

**doNotClear (2.0)**
Set this to true if you don't want empty lists to be removed. Default: false

**expandOnHover (2.0)**
How long (in ms) to wait before expanding a collapsed node (useful only if isTree: true). Default: 700

**isAllowed (function)**
You can specify a custom function to verify if a drop location is allowed. Default: function (placeholder, placeholderParent, currentItem) { return true; }

**isTree (2.0)**
Set this to true if you want to use the new tree functionality. Default: false

Comment: Ah yes I'd forgotten about that gem - sadly I'm looking for a pure javascript dragdrop api approach. This would be a great solution other than I really want to understand how to do it without jQuery

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: i agree with you @GNi33 but its just jquery based internal functions so i did't post the details still i mentioned some of them.